# Problem with logging into my virtual-machine Arch-linux?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, distributions

I have problem to log in to my VirtualBox Black Arch distro for a first time. It just booting up normal but when it asks me for a login and password and I try to type it in (I didn't create any account btw because there wasn't any option and also I am not able to call a console window ) it won't log in instead it keep aking me login and password in loops. Please what should I do? Thank you kindly for all your advices.

VirtualBox version 6.1.30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the default login is:

> Login: root
>
> password: blackarch

after that you should just be able to add a user with `useradd`.